# Is there a way to create a nuget pack specifying dependencies of .NET libraries?

Tags: nuget

One of my libs has a dependency on System.Configuration but this .NET lib is not included by default in most of project types on Visual Studio. Is there a way to instruct NuGet Package Manager to add this .NET reference when installing my lib?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [frameworkAssembly element](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference) in your package's nuspec file. This will cause NuGet to add a reference to the project when your package is installed.

```
<frameworkAssemblies>
  <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Configuration" />
</frameworkAssemblies>
```